# bootstrap carousel in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to load my images onto a carousel using ruby. However, when I enter in a certain code, I get an image that is not desired. Code is below.

```
<div class="page-wrap">
  <h1> Bikes</h1>
  <h2> The best source for bikes!</h2>

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @products.each_with_index do |product| %>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<%= 'product' %>" class="<%= product == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>"></li>
    <% end %>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel_images">
    <% @products.each_with_index do |product| %>
      <div class="item<%= " active" if product == @products.first %>">
        <% if product.image_url.present? %>
          <%= image_tag ("mbx.jpg") %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <%= product.name %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <% if product.image_url.present? %>
          <%= image_tag (product.image_url) %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <%= product.name %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

It shows the products when I put them in directly (mbx.jpg). However, it will not show them as a carousel but static.

Also, this is the code that shows up for the unwanted image in developer tools and I am not sure how to change it. I have already added the products using http://localhost:3000/products/new and apparently already have 7 but can't get any of them to show.

[Image here](http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/kitten-on-a-white-background-picture-id511458158?k=6&m=511458158&s=170667a&w=0&h=YS27-I0nj5x89iDRUZ2YxE77hEghPb0HNCWwPCrMmn8=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are following all [Bootstrap guidelines](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/). Here is what it should look like:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=777&fg=555&text=First slide" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=666&fg=444&text=Second slide" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=555&fg=333&text=Third slide" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems you should rename your `item` class to `carousel-item`.